# Круглая UIImage

Tags: ios, swift

Подскажите как сделать UIImage круглой и с обводкой. Делаю для отображения на карте.

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста как вы пытались решить эту задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложиить два варианта:

1. Использовать `UIImageView` и добавить скругление углов.

```swift
        let imageView = UIImageView(
            image: UIImage(named: "input") // исходная картинка
        )
        imageView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100) //размеры новой картинки
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.magenta.cgColor // цвет рамки
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 10 // толщина рамки
```

2. Сделать новую картинку на основе существующей, добавив рамку.

```swift
        let originalImage = UIImage(named: "input") //исходная картинка
        let imageSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100) //размеры новой картинки
        let imageWithBorder = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: imageSize).image { context in
            let imageFrame = CGRect(
                origin: .zero,
                size: imageSize
            )
            let circle = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: imageFrame)
            circle.addClip()
            image.draw(in: imageFrame)
            circle.lineWidth = 10 // толщина рамки
            UIColor.magenta.setStroke() // цвет рамки
            circle.stroke()
        }
```

Первый способ подходит, если вам нужно быстро отобразить картинку, не тратя ресурсы на отрисовку новой. Возможно он не подойдет для карт, если они не поддерживают `UIImageView`.

Второй способ создаст картинку, оптимизированную под размеры устройства, которая будет потреблять мало ресурсов при последующем использовании. Правда он потратит ресурсы на первичную отрисовку картинки и рамки.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Первый вариант не подошёл, я пробовал его раньше. Второй идеально подошел и теперь все работает!